# c# DES encryption not working as expected

Tags: c#, oracle, encryption, des

Previously we have a DES encryption function in Oracle, now we want to move it to C# code. However, when testing the 2 methods, they give the different output with the same input text and key. I noticed in Oracle code, it adds chr(0) to the end of string, while in C#, I use new byte[]{0,0} for the same, not sure if this causes the problem?

Oracle code:

```
create or replace 
function
encrypt_des(p_text varchar2, p_key varchar2) return varchar2 is
v_text varchar2(4000);
v_enc varchar2(4000);
raw_input RAW(128) ;
key_input RAW(128) ;
decrypted_raw RAW(2048);
begin
v_text := rpad( p_text, (trunc(length(p_text)/8)+1)*8, chr(0));
raw_input := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(v_text);
key_input := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(p_key);
 dbms_output.put_line(raw_input ); 
//display the raw_input

dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt(input => raw_input,key => 
key_input,encrypted_data =>decrypted_raw);
v_enc := rawtohex(decrypted_raw);

dbms_output.put_line(v_enc);

return v_enc;
end;
```

C# code:

```
        byte[] rgbKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("aaaaaaaa".Substring(0, 8));

        byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("9804ff20");
        var newbyte = inputByteArray.Concat(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }).ToArray();
        var rawinput= BitConverter.ToString(newbyte).Replace("-", "");
    //display the raw_input

        DESCryptoServiceProvider dCSP = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        dCSP.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        dCSP.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        dCSP.Key = rgbKey;
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, dCSP.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cStream.Write(newbyte, 0, newbyte.Length);
        cStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte num in mStream.ToArray())
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", num);
        }
        mStream.Close();
        var result= builder.ToString();
```

before encryption, I compared the raw_input in both methods (the line I commented in the code), and they are exactly the same, but after encryption, why I get different results?

Testing result:

```
Input text: 9804ff20
Key: aaaaaaaa
Oracle Raw input:39383034666632300000000000000000
C# raw input: 39383034666632300000000000000000
Oracle result: 29B63290034C40DAEF7A5D9608CC19B1
C# result: 29B63290034C40DA5FF660CB09F83313
```

Comment: Is chr(0) in Oracle unicode?  No, it seems it's ASCII, but your problem is likely to be encoding

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can adjust my code with the encoding?byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("9804ff20");

Comment: The first block (8 bytes) is right, which means your key is right and data is right and either your mode is ECB or it's CBC with the IV `{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }`.  The second block is wrong, meaning either your second block of data is wrong, or it's CBC.

Comment: I'm using the ECB mode you can see in the code. I understand there is something wrong of the second block of data, but what's wrong? I'd appreciate if you can take a look at the code.

Comment: Yes, the C# is using ECB. Neither "ECB" nor "CBC" are present in the Oracle code.  My suggestion is that your C# should be using CBC, but first set `dCSP.IV = new byte[8]`

Comment: Perfect! I made it, thanks for you advice.